# Integration when time dependent equation of state

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

I think it is easy but I am little confused. Can someone explain stepwise how to move from

$$
\dot{\rho}=-3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}(1+w)\rho
$$ 
to 
$$
\ln\frac{\rho_{re}}{\rho_{end}}=-3\int_{a_{end}}^{a_{re}}(1+w)\frac{da}{a} \, ?
$$
Of course we wanted to integrate from $t_{end}$ to $t_{re}$.

Comment: there is no integration in the time domain here. You can just "divide by the $\frac{1}{dt}$" on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This differential equation can be integrated by parts to obtain the result you want, just like @Sanya proposed. So you divide by $da/dt~ \rho$ to get to:
$$ \frac{d\rho}{\rho ~dt}\frac{dt}{da}=-3(1+w)\frac{1}{a}.$$
Now the $dt$ differentials *"cancel"* and we get:
$$ \frac{d\rho}{\rho ~da}=-3(1+w)\frac{1}{a}.$$
Now this DGL can be integrated by parts as usal: *"multiply"* by $da$ to get
$$ \frac{1}{\rho}d\rho=-3(1+w)\frac{1}{a}~da$$ and now integrate
\begin{align}\int^{\rho_{re}}_{\rho_{end}}\frac{1}{\rho}d\rho&=\int^{a_{re}}_{a_{end}}-3(1+w)\frac{1}{a}~da \\\\ \ln(\frac{\rho_{re}}{\rho_{end}})& = -3\int^{a_{re}}_{a_{end}}(1+w)\frac{1}{a}~da \end{align}
Disclaimer: I am physicist and so I am allowed to do fancy stuff with my differentials; all involved functions are "sufficiently good-natured".

Comment: Anything special with cancel and multiply to differential? It will be helpful for me if you point to  good references differentiating how it differs from normal multiplication of variables. Further question posted is from Cosmology. And my question is: w was function of time, but now it is function of time "only" through scale factor a---is it valid? I know scale factor can be used to play the role of time in cosmology.

Comment: Calculating with differentials: multipling, canceling and so on should be done carefully. Here is a question and an answer on the topic http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379773/cancelling-differentials. Such computations are actually changes of variables and because of that one needs to be carefull with function arguments, limits of integration and so on. To your question on $w$: yes time droped out of the equation you have something like $w(t(a))$. But $t(a)$ or $a(t)$ do not come out of the equation above you will need some auxiliary equations for that.